# How to turn of hardware acceleration only for specific screen in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview, crash

I am using React Native and have a Screen 'B' that's seems to crash everytime there is a goBack navigation triggered to come back to Screen 'A'. Also Screen 'B' uses multiple webviews with JS injections. If I go to my AndroidManifest.xml file inside android/app/src/main and make below change:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

then it starts working but then other features like camera view and elevation styling stops working, how do I only set hardware acceleration to false for my Screen 'B' activity?

Currently my AndroidManifest.xml activity looks like below:

```
      <activity
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hardware-acceleration-view could help, either by disabling acceleration for certain views or by turning it off in general and enabling where needed.

Be aware that react-native-hardware-acceleration-view just was added recently to npm.js. It might not be stable and it needs to be seen for how long it receives updates.